# How can I login as a different user in Facebook login dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I managed to develop an android application to read facebook updates of the user. 
I am using Facebook dialog for Authentication.

Once I have authenticated the user and allowed the application to access the account, the dialog quits and it is able to read the status. Perfect.

But I am not able to login as a different user. In all the further loads of dialog, it shows nothing. Seems like, it is authenticating the same user again and disappears.

How can I bring the content of the dialog visible again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, which I should have found hours before.

Facebook has its own logout call which will clear the cache and cookie.

facebook.logout(getBaseContext());
did the trick.

I know the qn was silly. Still, let it help someone else come up with the same doubt. :)